# Springboot REST API RestAssured testing project setup and project structure

Tags: spring-boot, rest-assured

I have a Springboot application that is a REST API and I would like to start adding RESTAssured integration tests with JUnit 5.

I also added folder structure to my src/test/java like

```
- src
    |- test
         |- java
              |- package com.me.myapp.unittests (contains JUnit 5 tests)
                   |- package com.me.myapp.unittests.controller
                   |- package com.me.myapp.unittests.service
              |- package com.me.myapp.restassuredtests (contains RestAssured with JUnit5 tests)
                   |- package com.me.myapp.restassuredtests .controller
```

Is this tipical structure when working with RestAssured tests or RestAssured tests should be moved to entirely separate project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can place the restassured IT tests under src/test/java under any package you want. So yes your structure is right. There is no need to move to entirely separate project